# How to use a variable defined in two nested for loops as stopargument for the thrid loop

Tags: bash

I have three loops for example that contain the code

```
for i in $words
do
height=$((20 + (10 * i)))
done

for j in {0..3}
do
x=$((10 + (15 * j)))
done

for k in $height
do 
y=$((110 - k)/2))
done
```

With $words containing the numbers

```
0 3 4 5
```

height will give

```
20 
50 
60 
70
```

x will give

```
10
25
40
55
```

and y should give

```
45
30
25
20
```

But the problem is that height is defined in one of the for loops so I can't use it as an argument for the last for loop. The table of height is also vertical and not horizontal. When I do a nested for loop I get too many rows.

My desired output should look like this using echo please
for example

```
echo "<$height> <$x> <$y>
```

and it should look like this

```
20   1O   40
50   25   30
60   40   25
70   55   20
```

Thank you

Comment: May be you want to add new elements to `height` instead of overriding it at each loop iteration. You can use `height="$height ..."`

Comment: How does x only have 4 values when your loop `for j in {0..22}` iterates 23 times?

Comment: Didn't see that, thank you for pointing out

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't want to nest loops and every loop will iterate the same number of times, you can use arrays to keep track of their values.

```
#!/bin/bash
# Create arrays to store each value
h_values=()
x_values=()
y_values=()
words="0 3 4 5"

for i in $words
do
# append an array with a calculated value
h_values+=( "$((20 + (10 * i)))" )
done

for j in {0..3}
do
x_values+=( "$((10 + (15 * j)))" )
done

# this loops over each element of h_values, the heights we calculated before
for k in "${h_values[@]}"
do 
y_values+=( "$(((110 - k)/2))" )
done

# C-style for loop to print the i-th index of each array in order
for ((i=0 ; i < ${#h_values[@]} ; i++)) ; do
  printf '%s %s %s\n' "${h_values[i]}" "${x_values[i]}" "${y_values[i]}"
done
```

With your word values I get this output:

```
20 10 45
50 25 30
60 40 25
70 55 20
```

Which doesn't quite match your expected output but is pretty close. Maybe the math is a little off somewhere.

Answer (score 0):

Try this [Shellcheck](https://www.shellcheck.net/)-clean code:

```
#! /bin/bash -p

words=( 0 3 4 5)

j=0
for i in "${words[@]}"; do
    height=$((20 + 10*i))
    x=$((10 + 15*j++))
    y=$(((110-height)/2))

    printf '%2d   %2d   %2d\n' "$height" "$x" "$y"
done
```

- The code uses an array to hold the "word" values because storing lists in strings is problematic in general, and there's rarely a need to do it in Bash code.